# On DIV click, check multiple checkbox (Not with same name)

Tags: javascript, php, html

My radio button are named dynamically. How to check all the checkbox on div click. The div and each radio has unique id. The div actually represent cards. I want upon clicking on card how to select all the listed radio in div
How to dynamically get all child node from javascript but check all the radio

```
<div id=<?= ($counter-1) ?> class="card categoryCard" style="width: 18rem;">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title"><?= $rows[$counter-1]["TICKETDESCRIPTION"]?></h5>
    <input type="radio" id=<?='TICKETDESCRIPTION'.($counter-1) ?> name="TICKETDESCRIPTION" >
    <p class="card-text"><label>RM <?= $rows[$counter-1]["TICKETPRICE"]?></label></p>
    <input type="radio" id=<?='TICKETPRICE'.($counter-1) ?> name="TICKETPRICE" >
  </div>
</div>
```

Below is my javascript code

```
$('.categoryCard').click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var radiobtn = document.getElementById("TICKETDESCRIPTION"+id);
    radiobtn.checked = true;
    alert(id);
});
```

Comment: why are you mixing up jQuery with javascript ?. that is not a good practice. `var radiobtn = document.getElementById("TICKETDESCRIPTION"+id);` this can be replaced with `var radiobtn = $("#TICKETDESCRIPTION"+id);`

Comment: you can select all the radio button using `'input[type=radio]'`

Comment: @AkhilAravind Yes, but lets say i have 2 radio button, it doesnt select all the radio button when i click on the div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
// assuming jquery

$('.categoryCard').click(function(e){
   $('input[type="radio"]', this).each( function( i) {
     $(this).prop('checked', true);

   });

});
```

Comment: can you explain what is function(i, el)?

Comment: For it to be check, should i use "attribute" instead of "property"?

Comment: @MrJ No, he is actually correct. This is because my i am looping and i need to make cards in such a way that each card has same radio button but different value.

Comment: actually it was little wrong, see update - but no - prop is the correct jquery method

see here : http://api.jquery.com/each/

Comment: Can explain why have "this" in $('input[type="radio"]', this)

Comment: in $('input[type="radio"]', this), this restricts the scope of the search to the .categoryCard element.

input[type="radio"] - returns all the radio buttons in the scope

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to implement the same. I've described the two ways.

> You must not use the ID as duplicate.
>
> ID is identifier for the elements, so it must not be duplicate.

```js
$('.categoryCard').click(function(e){
   $('input[type="radio"]', this).each( function( index, element) {
     $(element).prop('checked', true);

   });

});

$('.categoryCard').click(function(e){
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
   $('input[data-details="'+ id +'"]', this).each( function( index, element) {
     $(element).prop('checked', true);

   });

});
```

```css
.categoryCard{
border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
padding: 5px;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="1" class="card categoryCard" style="width: 18rem;">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Desc</h5>
    <input type="radio" name="TICKETDESCRIPTION">
    <p class="card-text">Price</p>
    <input type="radio" name="TICKETPRICE" >
  </div>
</div>

<!-- 2nd Method there must be no duplicate ID  -->

<div id="2" class="card categoryCard" style="width: 18rem;">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Desc</h5>
    <input type="radio" name="TICKETDESCRIPTION" data-details ="1">
    <p class="card-text">Price</p>
    <input type="radio" name="TICKETPRICE" data-details ="1" >
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this will help alot of people

Answer (score 1):

It can be also solved like this:-

```
$('.categoryCard').click(function(){
   $(this).find('input[type="radio"]').each(function() {
     $(this).prop('checked', true);
   });
});
```